# LDAP authentication using nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, authorization, ldapjs

For my angularJs app, i want to create an authentication by connecting to my company's LDAP using nodeJs to manage users authorization.
This is my current code, i'm getting this error:

*binding failed
status: 0
result: {"messageID":2,"protocolOp":"LDAPResult","status":0,"matchedDN":"","errorMessage":"","referrals":[],"controls":[]}*

Is this possible with a simple javascript binding?
Do any one have a good samples please ? 
Thank you in advance!

```js
'use strict';
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
const assert = require('assert');

var creds = {
  url: "ldap://*****************",
};

var baseDN = "OU=****,OU=Utilisateurs,OU=****,OU=****,OU=****,DC=***,DC=***,DC=local";
var user = 'LASTNAME Firstname';
var password = 'password';
var fullDN = 'uid=' + user + ',' + baseDN;

var opts = {
  filter: "(&(objectClass=user)(email=*****@***))",
  scope: "sub",
  password: "password",
  client: "email"
};

function authDN(user, baseDN, password, cb) {
 console.log('binding done');
  client.bind(baseDN,password, function (err) {
    client.unbind();
    cb(err === null, err);
    console.log('binding failed');
  });
}

function output(res, err) {    
  if (res) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(res);
  } else {
    console.log(['Error',err.code, err.dn, err.message ]);
  }
}

var client = ldap.createClient(creds);
authDN(client, 'server instance name', 'password', output);

  //serach method 
  client.search('CN=LASTNAME Firstname,OU=****,OU=Utilisateurs,OU=****,OU=****,OU=****,DC=***,DC=***,DC=local', opts, function(err, res) {
  assert.ifError(err);

  res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
    console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
  });
  res.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
    console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
  });
  //res.put(Context.REFERRAL,"follow");
  res.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('error: ' + err.message);
  });
  res.on('end', function(result) {
    console.log('status: ' + result.status);
    console.log('result: ' + result);
    process.exit(1);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i fixed it and i'm posting this here it may help somebody =)
The code below bind and authenticate.

```js
'use strict';
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
const assert = require('assert');

var creds = {
  url: "ldap://************.local:389",
  bindDN: "DC=***,DC=***,DC=local"
};

var opts = {
  filter: "(&(objectClass=user))",
  scope: "sub",
  client: "*"
};
//binding
function authDN(user, baseDN, password, cb) {
  client.bind(baseDN, password, function (err) {
    client.unbind();
    cb(err === null, err);
  });
}

function output(res, err) {    
  if (res) {
    console.log('success :' + res);
  } else {
    console.log(['Error :',err.code, err.dn, err.message ]);
  }
}

var client = ldap.createClient(creds);
authDN(client, 'username', 'password', output);

//search
  client.search('CN=*** ,OU=****,...,OU=****,DC=***,DC=***,DC=local', opts, function(err, res) {
  assert.ifError(err);

  res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
    console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
  });
  res.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
    console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
  });
  res.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('error: ' + err.message);
  });
  res.on('end', function(result) {
    console.log('status: ' + result.status);
    console.log('result: ' + result);
    process.exit(1);
  });

});
```